# glColor3f in OpenGl have little brightness

Tags: c, opengl, freeglut, opengl-1.x

I have a problem with my code in OpenGl
I need to do a game engine. 
I use freeglut library. 
I did this practise with old Visual Studio versions and I don't have this problem. But with the Visual Studio 2017 the attribute `glColor3f` is showed with little brightness. Why?

This is the code that I use for to show the texts:

```
char instrucciones3[100];
sprintf_s(instrucciones3, "PULSA 'ESC' SI QUIERES SALIR");
char *res4 = instrucciones3;
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); //This is the problem, I dont have alpha but the brightness is low.
glRasterPos3f(1.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
drawString(res4);

char instrucciones2[100];
sprintf_s(instrucciones2, "PULSA 'H' PARA COMENZAR PARTIDA ");
char *res3 = instrucciones2;
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glRasterPos3f(-10.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
drawString(res3);
```

---

Update:

[image: This is the result of my code]

The brightness is so low, but the model is good. I put `glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` in the new code but the result is the same.

---

Update2
This is my displayMe func:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0, 3, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

glRotatef(yaw, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(pitch, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(roll, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
GLfloat lightpos[] = { 5.0, 15., 5., 0. };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos);
```

Comment: I try to do this, but the result is the same. The brightness is so low, nearly to the black.

Comment: I dont use that.

Comment: Do you draw your text before or after drawing the model? Did you try swapping the order?

Comment: after the model, but if i draw the model after the texts the result is the same

Comment: I have this GLfloat lightpos[] = { 5.0, 15., 5., 0. };
 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos); Maybe, this is the problem?

Comment: OHHH this is the answer correct. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed function light model is applied on the text, too. This will cause arbitrary results, dependent on the current light settings ans current normal vector attribute. You have to disable lighting before you draw the text.

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

and you have to enable it before you draw the geometry

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

---

The parameters to [`glColor3f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml) have to be floating point values in the range [0.0, 1.0],

```
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

in compare to `glColor3ub`, where the parameters are integral values in the range [0, 255].

```
glColor3ub(0, 255, 255);
```

---

See [OpenGL Specification (Version 2.0) - 2.7. VERTEX SPECIFICATION; page 21](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec20.pdf)

> The commands to set RGBA colors are
>
> ```
> void Color{34}{bsifd ubusui}( T components );
> void Color{34}{bsifd ubusui}v( T components );
> ```
>
> The Color command has two major variants: `Color3` and `Color4`. The four value versions set all four values. The three value versions set R, G, and B to the provided values; A is set to 1.0.
>   [...] Versions of the Color and SecondaryColor commands that take floating-point
>   values **accept values nominally between 0.0 and 1.0**.
>   [...]
>
> ```
> GL        Type Conversion
> ubyte     c/(2^8 − 1)
> byte      (2c + 1)/(2^8 − 1)
> ushort    c/(2 16 − 1)
> short     (2c + 1)/(2^16 − 1)
> uint      c/(2^32 − 1)
> int       (2c + 1)/(2^32 − 1)
> float     c
> double    c
> ```

Comment: I try this but the result is the same

Comment: Rabbid your comment for Disable and Enable function was the solution THANKS YOUU!!

Comment: but your comment in my question were delete, but I dont do that. I try to found your comment but doesnt appear.

Comment: @Ana I extended the answer. I deleted the comment and added the comment to the answer (at the begin of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a texture somewhere? If so, try disabling texturing before drawing the other thing.